# Rails for Date format issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formatting

I am trying to output just the date on the generated line, but when I execute this code, which I am sure is not elegant at all, it gives me `undefined method 'strftime' for nil:NilClass`

```
<% @person.subordinates.each do |sub| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <% if sub.position == 'alumni' %>
        <p>
          <%= link_to(sekret_person_path(sub.position, sub.user_name)) do %>
            <strong><%= sub.fname %> <%= sub.lname %>,</strong>
          <% end %> <%= sub.startdate.strftime("%Y") %> - <%= sub.graddate.strftime("%Y") %>
        </p>   
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Further up in my code, I am using `@person.startdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")` without any issue, but I think my issue is that I am using the sub call, which is grabbing any people that are flagged as sub to this person.

Comment: I suppose `sub.startdate` or `sub.graddate` is nil, yes?

Comment: It is not. There is a datetime entered into it for some of the people in the database.

Comment: If the error is thrown on the eighth line of the code that you posted, then one of those must be `nil` because that's what the error is saying.

Comment: @jvillian I understand why you are saying that but further up in my code, I am using `@person.startdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`, which works properly, the actual DB is person, not sub. Sub is a ?variable call to the person DB for anyone that falls under another person as a subordinate.

Comment: One of the `subordinates` of your `@person` has `nil` in either its `startdate` or its `graddate`.

Comment: It does not matter if further up you are using it, inside this loop there is a `nil` value somewhere, one of the subordinates has to have a nil value OR there is something else going on with the subordinates getting returned by this call.  What if you remove that `strftime` method for a second and just output the date inside the loop in order to verify, can you try that?  Does everything in the loop return and show a start date?

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes, if I remove `strftime` the loop runs without error.

Comment: and it shows a date for every object inside the loop?

Comment: @RockwellRice it does not, I went back and added a value and it works fine. I didn't think all of the values needed to be there for the loop to process, so many times if there is a blank in the place it just outputs blank. I will make sure that it is a required field.

Comment: Right, so just to be clear, because it will help down the road, and others have pointed it out here, a `nil:NilClass` means that a variable is nil and so you cannot call the method on it, in this case `strftime` was the method.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says that one of your attributes is nil. The sytax is correct. Try debugging with:

```
@person.subordinates.select { |sub| sub.startdate.nil? || sub.graddate.nil? }
```

The elements that are retrieved on this line will be the ones that are giving you errors, because you are trying to run `nil.strftime('%Y')`, which makes sense.

You should use a condition on your `.erb` to stop it, like:

```
<%= sub.startdate && sub.startdate.strftime("%Y") %> - <%= sub.graddate && sub.graddate.strftime("%Y") %>
```

It is not an error with Rails.

Comment: You were correct, the loop was working properly, one of the fields was nil.

Answer (score 2):

`strftime` is being called on `nil` object. Make sure you are calling `strftime` on a `date`, `time`, or `datetime` object.

Refer to `strftime` on rails apidock - https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: If you see my first comment on the main post, you will see I am calling it on the exact same data, it is just being called in a different way, and I do not think I am making the link properly. I am just not sure how to get there. The data is in the person database, not a sub database, as that is pulling from the person DB.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this that will guard against `nil`s would be:

```
<%= sub.startdate&.strftime("%Y") %> - <%= sub.graddate&.strftime("%Y") %>
```

That way you don't have to add a conditional to make sure that any method/attribute in the chain exists prior to calling them. This works because of the safe navigation operator, which is explained in depth here: https://rubyinrails.com/2017/11/17/safe-navigation-operator-ampersand-dot-in-ruby/

Comment: I dont think you will need the safe navigator after ‘sub’, just after ‘startdate’ and ‘graddate’ because each ‘sub’ is the result of an iteration of the model.